# Display flash message on user update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to display a flash message in the index page when I update a "Player" but I'm quite new with Rails and haven't figured it out.

My update func looks like this :

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @player.update(player_params)
                format.html {
                    flash[:success] = @player.name + ' was successfully updated.'
                    redirect_to @player
                    }
.
.
. ( points for brevity )
```

Is there a way to track events so the flash gets displayed at the right time or how should I proceed?

Comment: Do you display the flash in the page ? This may help you :  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I needed to use the flash.keep method to carry the flash into the next request.

```
def show
  flash.keep
end
```

Thanks to Pavan and Baldrick

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: "#{@player.name} was successfully updated."}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This displays the message in the page of the player ( `players/id` ) . Is there a way to display it in the index ?